# How can I use CreateFunction to calculate age based on their birthday on mySQL?

Tags: mysql, create-function

I have a table with date of birth and I want to use a CreateFunction to calculate their age.

So I was thinking along the lines of extracting year from current date - Year for their date of birth (using YEAR() function as shown below)

The function below doesn't seem to work so any help would be appreciated!

```
DELIMITER $$
 
CREATE FUNCTION customer_age(DateOfBirth DATE)
RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
    DECLARE age DATE
    
    SET age = YEAR(curdate())- YEAR(DateOfBirth);
    
    RETURN (age);
    
    END $$
    
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an integer not a date,

See example

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION customer_age(DateOfBirth DATE)
> RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE age INT;
>     SET age = YEAR(curdate())- YEAR(DateOfBirth);
>     
>     RETURN age;
>     
>     END
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT customer_age('1970-01-01')
> ```
>
> ```
> | customer_age('1970-01-01') |
> | -------------------------: |
> |                         51 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b938df8710ec7478145ece67e17edd26)*